# Autosize Rows for Datagridview in VB.net not working

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, visual-studio-2017, row, autosize

**Hi, i'm making a memo type of data grid with Dynamic data from Database
and somehow i cannot make the rows auto resize.
i tried pretty much everything, here's some snippet of my code which i put on Form Load sub:**

```
    DataGridView2.Columns(0).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
    DataGridView2.Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells
    DataGridView2.Columns(2).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    DataGridView2.Columns(2).DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True
    DataGridView2.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCellsExceptHeaders
```

**Which came out like this:**

[image]

**After That i tried using this on  DataGridView2.CellPainting Event**

```
    If e.Value Is Nothing Then Return
    Dim s = e.Graphics.MeasureString(e.Value.ToString(), DataGridView2.Font)

    If s.Width > DataGridView2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Width Then

        Using gridBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(DataGridView2.GridColor), backColorBrush As Brush = New SolidBrush(e.CellStyle.BackColor)

            Using gridLinePen As Pen = New Pen(gridBrush)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColorBrush, e.CellBounds)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Left, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1, e.CellBounds.Right, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(gridLinePen, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Top, e.CellBounds.Right - 1, e.CellBounds.Bottom - 1)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Value.ToString(), DataGridView2.Font, Brushes.Black, e.CellBounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault)
                DataGridView2.Rows(e.RowIndex).Height = CInt((s.Height * Math.Ceiling(s.Width / DataGridView2.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Width)))
                e.Handled = True
            End Using
        End Using
    End If
```

**which came out like this:**

[image]

Tried fiddling with all properties but i seems unable to figure it out, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process I followed:

- Dropped a new datagridview on a form (actually I dragged it out of the datasources window, because I already had a dataset in the project)

[image]

- Chose edit columns, chose a column, clicked `[...]` next to DefaultCellStyle for one of the string columns, set WrapMode to True

[image]

- Set `AutoSizeRowsMode` of the DGV to AllCells

[image]

- Inserted a long string into the underlying datatable the dgv was bound to:

[image]

- And the result wrapped:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i tried it but it still came out like mine. i think the problem was i dynamically populate the DGV with dataset. Gonna Try populate it with normal SQL DataReader.

Comment: What does "dynamically populate the DGV with dataset" mean ? DataSets don't contain data; they contain datatables (and datatables contain rows that contain data). The datagridview I screnshotted above is bound to a datatable (inside a dataset), and when that datatable is filled with data, the DGV rows resize to show it..

Answer (score 0):

You can consider centering the elements in the DataGridView：

```
    DataGridView2.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
    DataGridView2.RowsDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
```

Result looks like:

[image]